# How to handing pop up pinentry question with ansible playbook?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, terminal, ansible

I am using the Ansible playbook to make a VM template with the docker credential store installed.

However, there is a problem with the step of init the pass store,

my step is similar to the step of the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996117/how-to-use-docker-credential-pass-to-login-to-a-private-registry

which is install gpg -> generate key-> install pass-> `pass init <gpg key id>`-> `pass insert docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check` -> `pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check` -> docker login again

I found that I cannot docker login if I don't go through pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check step, the docker login would fail `Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: pass store is uninitialized`

The problem is I cannot find a way to config the play of this task to handle the pop-up block when the playbook run `pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check`, the block is shown below:

[image]

Because I need the playbook to do automation of deploying VM,
Is there any method that can either init the pass without `pass show docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check` or **the syntax of writing the playbook to handle this pop-up pinentry?**

Comment: Maybe [How to initialize docker-credentials-pass #102](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/102) or [How to use docker-credential-pass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66626548/6771046) helps ...